# css() not setting the height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, width

I am trying to give my container element height and width via jQuery `.css()` but my code is setting it as window height and width. Can anyone please tell me why is the code not working?

Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var H = $(window).height();
    var W = $(window).width();
    var h = W / 1.625;
    var w = H * 1.625;
    if (w > W) {
        $("#container").css("height", h + 'px').css("maxWidth", W + 'px;');
    else {
        $('#container').css("maxHeight", H + 'px').css("width", w + 'px;');
    }
});
```

Comment: This also depends on what display property you've set for `#container`. Plus your code has errors.

Comment: use firefox's firebug extension. It is a great tool to observe what's happening on the page

Comment: don't call `.css()` in a chain like that when it's not necessary; call it with both args in a single call, like this: `.css({height:h+'px', maxWidth: W+'px'});`

Comment: Is the `#container` a block element?

Comment: possibl problem: the semi-colon you've got in the `'px;'` on the maxWidth and width settings. You don't need a semi-colon here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your if statement is missing a `}`, so won't work in the first place. Change:

```
if(w>W)  
{
    $("#container").css("height", h+'px').css("maxWidth", W+'px;');
    else
        ...
```

To:

```
if(w>W)  
{
    $("#container").css("height", h+'px').css("maxWidth", W+'px;');    
}                
else
    ...
```

Also as you're setting multiple CSS properties, you can combine these into one CSS method by passing the properties in as an object:

```
if (w>W) 
{
    $("#container").css({height:h, maxWidth:w});
}
...
```

jQuery sorts out the `px` for you in most cases. See jQuery's [`css()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more info. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help but somehow the multiple CSS properties were causing error as unknown token and the problem was ";" and the braces that I figured out eventually with some trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing brace `}` on the `if`, so your code should look like,

```
if (w > W) {
    $("#container").css("height", h + 'px').css("maxWidth", W + 'px;');  
}
else {
    $('#container').css("maxHeight", H + 'px').css("width", w + 'px;');
}
```

You could improve your code readability by, passing your css properties as a part of an object, as opposed to chaining, as adding many properties is rather helpful when you pass them as an object.

```
if (w > W) {
    $("#container").css({
         "height": h + 'px', 
         "max-width": W + 'px'
    });  
}
else {
    $("#container").css({
         "max-height": H + 'px', 
         "width": w + 'px'
    });
}
```